# $|D_{18}|=18=2 \times 3^2$, then $D_{18}$ have 2-sylow and 3-sylow subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G=D_{18}=\langle a , b |  a^9=b^2=1 , bab=a^{-1} \rangle$. Then $D_{18}=S_3 \times Z_3$?

$|D_{18}|=18=2 \times 3^2$, then $D_{18}$ have 2-sylow and 3-sylow subgroups.  3-sylow subgroup of $D_{18}$ which is subgroup ?

Comment: $D_{18}$ isn't isomorphic to $S_3 \times Z_3$ as the first has an element of order 9 and the second does not.

Comment: No. order of $D_{18}$ is 18.

Comment: Right, the number of elements in each group is 18. But one has an element who's order is 9. The order of a group has a different meaning than the order of an element in a group.

Answer (score 2):

Since 9 is the highest power of 3 dividing the order of $G$, a sylow-3 subgroup of $D_{18}$ has order 9. Your presentation for $G$ yields a subgroup of order 9, namely the cyclic subgroup generated by the element $a$.

Similarly a sylow-2 subgroup is generated by $b$.

Like I mentioned in the comments, $D_{18}$ isn't isomorphic to $S_3×Z_3$ as the one has an element of order 9 and the other does not.